# Check the words in inputbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way so that when I input in a inputbox then after leaving that box JavaScript automatically check the inputs in inputbox.?

Like when we creat account in gmail or facebook and when we type our name it automatically checks the name ...
Same with javascript for regular expression .. Either it is text or number ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What's your question exactly?

Comment: you can addEventListener `blur` for that input

Comment: I mean to say at the time I stop writing in a input box it JavaScript automatically checks the inputs

Comment: Is this helpful

Comment: Well, no. Because I understand your question, but we need to know where you stand. So basically, [what](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [have you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) [tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't have any idea of this.    ... But yeh I implemented javascript with mousehover ,submit button

Comment: But I don't know how to to this...??

Comment: Well, like @ABUdhay said, register an [eventlistener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur). Then you just have to write your own validation function. If you got stuck somewhere, post us the code and explain where you got stuck exactly.

Comment: Thank you guys ... I really appreciate your help .... I also want some good books on javascript and HTML ... Can you guys refers some?

Comment: <input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">

Comment: Guys but I want to run JavaScript at the time I stop writing in inputbox ...

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are looking for something like this:

```
var timeout;
function callValidate() {
    // clear timeout if any key is pressed before validate is executed (cancel execution of validate function)
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }
    // since there is no way to tell when/if someone stopped typing
    // wait 0.8 seconds before validation is executed
    timeout = setTimeout(validation, 800)
}

function validation() {
    // do the validation eg:
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    console.log(!isNaN(parseFloat(name.value)) && isFinite(name.value) ? 'Number entered...' : 'Text entered...');
}
```

your input field should look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="callValidate()">
```